# Issue with Video Splitter

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I'm trying to integrate a video splitter for CVBS signal into my circuit. The Video amplifier I'm using is ADA4853 from Analog Device.
[image: Circuit for ADA4853]

In the datasheet, there's a sample circuit for video splitter and I'm following that strictly.
At the output, the signal going through a TBU (R is around 7.5Ohm) and an analog mux (DG409LEDY-GE3) (Ron is about 17Ohm). Hence I'm matching the output impedance at R3 and R5 with the resistor of 50.5 Ohm. And because I don't have that value in house, I'm using  63.4 Ohm instead.

When I connect the output of the splitter to a TV, the video signal only shows up for a split second, then disappears, then shows up again. I tried to probe it with a scope and this is what's shown for the output signal
[image: Output signal]

Here's what I have tried and failed to resolve the issue

- Changed from x2 gain to unity again (remove R1 and R8 and short R2 and R6).
- Changed various R3 and R5 to see if the impedance matching was the issue
- Checked my control signal Amp1_EN and Amp2_EN from the microcontroller to see if they had any issue or not. And they were constantly on during the process

What I haven't tried is to put a 75Ohm at the positive terminal of the OpAmp. Other than that, I don't know what else I need to do. Is the issue I'm having related to impedance mismatch or it's something completely different? Any advice would be great.
Thank you

Comment: I don't see any splitter app circuit in the datasheet.  Your feedback resistors are 1/2 the value in the datasheet app circuit.  The amp expects to see a 150 ohm resistance to GND on its output. Make sure the decoupling is very close to the power pins.

Comment: I thought as long as the value of the Rf and Rg to be equal, it's good. And I even try the unity gain (buffer circuit) by shorting 2 terminals on Rf footprint and leave Rg open. But the video signal does not come out right.
And in the App note, they don't specifically mention about the splitter circuit, but just a simple video amplifier. So I tied both positive terminals of 2 amps together and amplified the signal to make my own splitter